# Replacing 2 layers of tile, can I put plywood + Ditra mat OVER lathe and scratch?

Tags: tile, underlayment, demolition

We're redoing our 2nd-floor 7' x 10' laundry room, including new / moved cabinets and flooring. The existing tile was ~1/4" lower than the vinyl plank outside the room, so I (naively) assumed we'd tear up the tile, add a membrane, and retile. Easy peasy and we'd have a level transition!

...until we removed the cabinets, and found that we have TWO layers of tile all on a 1/8" lathe + scratch bed. The bed is wall to wall, but the tile stopped at the cabinets. The adhesion below both layers of tile is abysmal. Seriously, maybe 5% coverage - and the bottom tile looks like they used the same 1/8 V-notch from the scratch to only back-butter the tiles. The bed itself looks fine, aside from a few 1" spots where the lathe is exposed.

Is there a reason to rip up the scratch bed to add another 1/2" of plywood, or can we leave the bed, add 1/4" or 3/8" of ply, then membrane and tile?  Thank you!

*Edit with pics
[image: Outer floor and first layer of tile]

[image: second layer of tile and scratch coat]

Comment: A picture or two may help people assess it. It's hard to know based only on a text description.

Comment: Read the documentation with your uncoupling membrane. Typically you can't just slap down any old thickness of underlayment plywood. I think that Ditra, for instance, requires a 3/8" minimum thickness.